# Charging 4 parallel banks of 4 in series LifePO4, 16 total batteries. that have been top balanced

Tags: batteries, parallel, series, lifepo4

16 each LifePO4 batteries. 12.8Vdc 300Ah (Jita), an alleged internal BMS, charge by four SunGold Power SP6548 inverters, configured so two are providing 120VAC for phase 1 and two are providing 120VAC for phase 2, phase 2 is 180 degrees out. Each inverter has a charger that may be configured for minimum and maximum outputs. Will these charge ok? Should we have an equalizer on each bank of 4? (recommended to us by someone to do so).

The batteries are connected four in series, then in parallel with the other groups of four, via two victron busses bonded together (1000 amp max).
[image]